# Given a single arbitrary unit vector, what is the best method to compute an arbitrary orthogonal unit vector?

Tags: math, vector, 3d, linear-algebra, orthogonal

Essentially the same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049509/given-vector-of-one-axis-how-do-i-find-vectors-of-other-two-axes/3049709#3049709), but in a non-programming context. A suggested solution is take { y, -x, **0** }. This would work for all vectors that have an x or y component, but fails if the vector is equal to + or - { 0, 0, **1** }. In this case we would get { 0, 0, **0** }.

My current solution (in c++):

```
// floating point comparison utilizing epsilon
bool is_equal(float, float);

// ...

vec3 v = /* some unit length vector */

// ...

// Set as a non-parallel vector which we will use to find the 
//   orthogonal vector. Here we choose either the x or y axis.
vec3 orthog;
if( is_equal(v.x, 1.0f) )
  orthog.set(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
else
  orthog.set(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// Find orthogonal vector
orthog = cross(v, orthog);
orthog.normalize();
```

This method works, but I feel that there may be a better method and my searches turn up nothing more.

---

### [EDIT]

Just for fun I did a quick code up of naive implementations of each of the suggested answers in c++ and verified they all worked (though some don't always return a unit vector naturally, I added a noramlize() call where needed).

My original idea:

```
vec3 orthog_peter(vec3 const& v)
{
  vec3 arbitrary_non_parallel_vec = v.x != 1.0f ? vec3(1.0, 0.0f, 0.0f) : vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  vec3 orthog = cross(v, arbitrary_non_parallel_vec);

  return normalize( orthog );
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19650362/2507444

```
vec3 orthog_robert(vec3 const& v)
{
  vec3 orthog;
  if(v.x == 0.0f && v.y == 0.0f)
    orthog = vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  else if(v.x == 0.0f)
    orthog = vec3(1.0f, v.z / v.y, 1.0f);
  else if(v.y == 0.0f)
    orthog = vec3(-v.z / v.x, 1.0f, 1.0f);
  else
    orthog = vec3(-(v.z + v.y) / v.x, 1.0f, 1.0f);

  return normalize(orthog);
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19651668/2507444

```
// NOTE: u and v variable names are swapped from author's example
vec3 orthog_abhishek(vec3 const& v)
{
  vec3 u(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  float u_dot_v = dot(u, v);

  if(abs(u_dot_v) != 1.0f)
    return normalize(u + (v * -u_dot_v));
  else
    return vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19658055/2507444

```
vec3 orthog_dmuir(vec3 const& v)
{
  float length = hypotf( v.x, hypotf(v.y, v.z));
  float dir_scalar = (v.x > 0.0) ? length : -length;
  float xt = v.x + dir_scalar;
  float dot = -v.y / (dir_scalar * xt);

  return vec3(
    dot * xt, 
    1.0f + dot * v.y, 
    dot * v.z);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's one way to go about it. Let a vector (a, b, c) be given. Solve the equation (a, b, c) dot (aa, bb, cc) = 0 for aa, bb, and cc (and ensuring that aa, bb, and cc are not all zero), so (aa, bb, cc) is orthogonal to (a, b, c). I've used Maxima (http://maxima.sf.net) to solve it.

```
(%i42) solve ([a, b, c] . [aa, bb, cc] = 0, [aa, bb, cc]), a=0, b=0;
(%o42)                 [[aa = %r19, bb = %r20, cc = 0]]
(%i43) solve ([a, b, c] . [aa, bb, cc] = 0, [aa, bb, cc]), a=0;
                                        %r21 c
(%o43)              [[aa = %r22, bb = - ------, cc = %r21]]
                                          b
(%i44) solve ([a, b, c] . [aa, bb, cc] = 0, [aa, bb, cc]), b=0;
                             %r23 c
(%o44)              [[aa = - ------, bb = %r24, cc = %r23]]
                               a
(%i45) solve ([a, b, c] . [aa, bb, cc] = 0, [aa, bb, cc]);
                        %r25 c + %r26 b
(%o45)         [[aa = - ---------------, bb = %r26, cc = %r25]]
                               a
```

Note that I've solved special cases first (a = 0 and b = 0, or a = 0, or b = 0) since the solutions found aren't all valid for some components equal to zero. The %r variables which appear are arbitrary constants. I'll set them equal to 1 to get some specific solutions.

```
(%i52) subst ([%r19 = 1, %r20 = 1], %o42);
(%o52)                    [[aa = 1, bb = 1, cc = 0]]
(%i53) subst ([%r21 = 1, %r22 = 1], %o43);
                                          c
(%o53)                   [[aa = 1, bb = - -, cc = 1]]
                                          b
(%i54) subst ([%r23 = 1, %r24 = 1], %o44);
                                  c
(%o54)                   [[aa = - -, bb = 1, cc = 1]]
                                  a
(%i55) subst ([%r25 = 1, %r26 = 1], %o45);
                                c + b
(%o55)                 [[aa = - -----, bb = 1, cc = 1]]
                                  a
```

Hope this helps. Good luck & keep up the good work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Maxima, but from what I gather from the output and your notes, aren't you still solving for a very specific set of input vectors (where a = 0 and b = 0)? 

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "Note that I've solved special cases first ... since the solutions found aren't all valid for some components equal to zero". I need to solve for any arbitrary input unit vector (title updated to note this), and this still only seems to be solving a subset.

Comment: In the solution you get in this case, if a = 0 you have a division by zero. For example, if the input vector is { 0, 0, 1 } you get { -(1/0), 1, 1 } which is not a valid solution. Maybe I am misunderstanding.

Comment: @PeterClark You are correct that the solutions given aren't valid for all inputs. Each one covers a different set of conditions, so that all together, they cover all inputs. You'll notice that other respondents give similar case-by-case solutions -- e.g. "If the point u already lies on an axis, then just choose any other axis for point v". I've organized the solutions so that they go from the narrowest special case to the most general. By the time you get to the general case, you've ruled out the special cases for which the general solution is invalid.

Comment: @PeterClark When you have special cases to handle, in this problem or any other, it is useful to organize them from most specific to most general, e.g. if (special case 1) ... else if (special case 2) ... else /* most general case */ .... As you fall through the conditions, you rule out one special case after another, so by the time you get to the end, you've ruled out all the special cases and you are therefore in the most general case.

Comment: Oh ok, it wasn't clicking that the second snippet of code was 4 unique solution. It makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use [Householder reflectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation).

We can find a reflector Q that maps our vector to a multiple of (1,0,0). Applying Q to (0,1,0) will give a vector perpendicular to our vector. One advantage of this method is that it applies to any number of dimensions; another is that we can 
get the other vector(s) perpendicular to the original and the new: apply Q to (0,0,1). It might sound complicated, but here's the C code for 3d (xp,yp,zp is the required vector, and has length 1; as written everything is a double, but you could use float instead and use hypotf instead of hypot)

```
l = hypot( x, hypot(y,z));
s = (x > 0.0) ? l : -l;
xt = x + s;
dot = -y/(s*xt);
xp = dot*xt;
yp = 1.0 + dot*y;
zp = dot*z;
```

Comment: Perhaps l = sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z), saving one square root, one mulitply, and two function calls.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a C version which uses the dominant axis to give a more deterministic result.

The caller needs to normalize the result of `ortho_v3_v3`.

```c
inline int axis_dominant_v3_single(const float vec[3])
{
    const float x = fabsf(vec[0]);
    const float y = fabsf(vec[1]);
    const float z = fabsf(vec[2]);
    return ((x > y) ?
           ((x > z) ? 0 : 2) :
           ((y > z) ? 1 : 2));
}

/**
 * Calculates \a p - a perpendicular vector to \a v
 *
 * \note return vector won't maintain same length.
 */
void ortho_v3_v3(float p[3], const float v[3])
{
    const int axis = axis_dominant_v3_single(v);

    assert(p != v);

    switch (axis) {
        case 0:
            p[0] = -v[1] - v[2];
            p[1] =  v[0];
            p[2] =  v[0];
            break;
        case 1:
            p[0] =  v[1];
            p[1] = -v[0] - v[2];
            p[2] =  v[1];
            break;
        case 2:
            p[0] =  v[2];
            p[1] =  v[2];
            p[2] = -v[0] - v[1];
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose a point v that is not equal to zero and not on the line joining origin with the given unit vector u.

As already suggested, you can choose a unit vector on any axis so long as that point satisfies the above condition. If the point u already lies on an axis, then just choose any other axis for point v.

Then you need to solve the equation `(v + tu).u = 0`. (just solve for t)

Ofcourse you will need to normalize it to get the orthogonal unit vector.

[image]

Comment: Why do we solve for `**(v + tu)**.u = 0` instead of `**v.u** = 0`? When you say we take v as a point, not equal to zero, and not on the line joining the origin with u (meaning if we view v as a vector from the origin, it is not some multiple of u) - doesn't `v+tu` just give the parametric equation of a line where v is a point on the line and u is the line's direction (thus it is parallel to u, and this equation is never true)?

Comment: @PeterClark See my updated answer. I have uploaded the image.